# MATLAB: Imagesc colormap doesn't reflect colorbar colors when using "set(gca,'ColorScale','log')"

Tags: matlab, colorbar, colormap

I've encountered a discrepancy within my imagesc figure between the value of the Index of a point and the color it is supposed to be according to the colorbar within my code.
I managed to reproduce this "error" using a simple script that you can try :

```
MyImage = pascal(10);
figure
hold on
im=imagesc(1:10,1:10, MyImage);
set(gca,'ColorScale','log')
h = colorbar;
colormap(hsv(5))
```

As you'll notice some squares do not have the color that it should have according to the colorbar, for example the point [X,Y]=[3 9] has index 45, which should be Yellow according to the colorbar, yet it is in red. Same with [X,Y]=[7 6] with index 462 appears yellow but should be green. There are several other points that have this discrepancy.
When I remove the "set(gca,'ColorScale','log')" line there doesn't appear to be this issue (even more obvious with my original images) so I suspect the error is related to this.
I'm not sure what I've done wrong, I have spent hours ripping my hair over this so any help is much appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think this is wrong at all. I have the feeling that it may be a bug, or "unexpected behaviour". What could be happening is that there is an internal conversion of data to "color index", and this last one is [0-1]. Then, at discretizing the coloromap, it assumes this "color index" is linear, instead of log.  I suspect this because if you look at `[3 9]`, but set `colormap(hsv(50))`, its color suddenly seems about right. So I think its a problem of the discretization of colors in the image being applied assuming linear colormap. Not your issue, but arguably a matlab bug.

Comment: Thx for the reply. It's reassuring that the problem isn't on my end but quite disheartening if this is a matlab bug. I believe I noticed the same error if I use contourf as well.

Would you know of a workaround for this? Using a linear scale is not possible with my data, and while using a large colormap helps (the problem is still present, just less obvious depending on the data) it makes it harder to assign values based on colors when there are 10 different shades of green and no clear cutoff.

Comment: I managed to find an interesting answer here https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/737702-how-to-get-logarithmic-colorbar-in-matlab-r2012a-for-3d-surface-plot which seems relevant to my issue although I am not sure if I understand it correctly

Comment: Feel free to asnwer it here :)